# How to convert "YYYYMM" format to "YYYY-MM-00"?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a sample table in mysql

```
id     yearmonth     
1      202001        
2      202002
3      202011
4      202012
5      201912
6      201911
```

The desired table in mysql is

```
id     yearmonth  
 1     2020-01-00
 2     2020-02-00
 3     2020-11-00
 4     2020-12-00
 5     2019-12-00
 6     2019-11-00
```

As we don't have day value in yearmonth column in the first table, we can replace with a default value.

Looking for your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `00` in DATE's datatype value DAY part is not correct. Do you want the final value to have string datatype?

Comment: No, I'm looking for date_format. Not string format.

Comment: Those aren't valid dates, there's no day 0 in the month.

Comment: Yes, but I just took the day as default one. I'm not really use it anywhere. I can replace 00 with 01. I'm just looking for the way to convert into YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: *I can replace 00 with 01.* You MUST if you want to have stable solution. For example, `SELECT CAST(yearmonth*100+1 AS DATE) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function for the same.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('202001','%Y%m');
Output:
2020-01-00
```

If you want to set `day` as a default value. Just use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('202001','%Y%m'), '%Y-%m-01');
Output:
2020-01-01
```

As @Akina mentioned that it is dependent on `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and might lead to `null` result. You can look for this alternative

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT('202010',4) , '-' , RIGHT('202010',2) , '-01');
```

If you want it to `date` type then you can use `CAST` explicit.

```
SELECT CAST( CONCAT(LEFT('202010',4) , '-' , RIGHT('202010',2) , '-01') AS DATE);
```

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8bd304992f3056b3d7a1ce39ea5fb73) not agreed with you... both queries returns NULL.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine in my local, let me check you fiddle too.

Comment: Your query validity depends on server's SQL mode - i.e. it is NOT valid in general. Because ANY server settings change may kill the application, and the restore may be very expensive.

Comment: @NikhilGarakapati That is your choice... and your field of rakes.

Comment: @Akina Okay, I didn't about the mode of SQL. Can you answer what would be exact way to convert into YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: @Akina, is it something related to `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode.

Comment: NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, more precisely.

Comment: @Akina, please check the alternative and guide us.

Comment: @NikhilGarakapati, please check the alternative, it is not dependent on such modes and working fine even in the fiddle.

Comment: Your alternative will give string datatype output which is safe only when this value will be used in MySQL in DATE context (for example, while updating DATE datatype column). In other cases you must add explicit CAST.

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenate the yearmonth column data value with the default day value you want then use `STR_TO_DATE` to change to date format:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(yearmonth,'01'), '%Y%m%d') FROM test;
```

Or using `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(yearmonth,'01'), '%Y-%m-%d') FROM test;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZ1RQFMkboRzzmj5VMA3rU/1)